# How can I find out what programs are using sound in Linux?

Tags: linux, audio, alsa

Is there anyway of knowing what binaries are using the sound system/server ? 
Like seeing something in the `/proc` directory (or `/dev`) ?

After a while ALSA stops working , and I would like to know why.

Answer (score 16):

One of the following commands might give you what you are after:

```
burhan@Ganymede:~$ lsof /dev/snd/*
COMMAND    PID   USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
pulseaudi 1142 burhan  mem    CHR  116,3          7885 /dev/snd/pcmC0D0p
pulseaudi 1142 burhan   21u   CHR  116,5      0t0 7887 /dev/snd/controlC0
pulseaudi 1142 burhan   28u   CHR  116,5      0t0 7887 /dev/snd/controlC0
pulseaudi 1142 burhan   36r   CHR 116,33      0t0 6351 /dev/snd/timer
pulseaudi 1142 burhan   37u   CHR  116,3      0t0 7885 /dev/snd/pcmC0D0p


burhan@Ganymede:~$ fuser -v /dev/snd/*
                     USER PID ACCESS COMMAND
/dev/snd/controlC0:  burhan     1142 F.... pulseaudio
/dev/snd/pcmC0D0p:   burhan     1142 F...m pulseaudio
/dev/snd/timer:      burhan     1142 f.... pulseaudio
```

On this system, pulseaudio is the only thing making use of the sound device but this is a fresh Ubuntu 11.04 VM. You may have other things listed.

Comment: I've been using lsof wrong for years. Smh. Thanks for this post.

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure about the sound interfaces in */proc*, but if you have [PulseAudio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PulseAudio) running, you can get this information from the [PulseAudio Volume Control](http://0pointer.de/lennart/projects/pavucontrol/), a GTK based tool. On Ubuntu, it is installed from the **pavucontrol** package.

It lets you see all the applications using the sound streams, and lets you control the volume levels for each stream individually (in addition to the volume of the channel itself).

[image]

Answer (score 6):

If your Linux installation is using PulseAudio, then it is possible to

**List all processes which are connected to your pulse audio**

run this command `pactl list clients`

---

However, it will give you POSSIBLE sound-making processes, if you really want to:

***catch* the process making sound** then run this command:

`watch -n0.5 'pacmd list-sink-inputs | tee -a sound-inputs.log'`

and after a while you will see what processes are making sound, they could disappear fast, this is why `tee -a sound-inputs.log` command is storing/logging in `sound-inputs.log` all information, and you can review which process **exactly** is *making noise* now.

you can review it by `less sound-inputs` command, an example output is below:

```
0 sink input(s) available.
0 sink input(s) available.
0 sink input(s) available.
1 sink input(s) available.
    index: 277
    driver: <protocol-native.c>
    flags: START_CORKED 
    state: RUNNING
    sink: 0 <alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo>
    volume: front-left: 55420 /  85% / -4.37 dB,   front-right: 55420 /  85% / -4.37 dB
            balance 0.00
    muted: no
    current latency: 35.85 ms
    requested latency: 7.52 ms
    sample spec: float32le 2ch 44100Hz
    channel map: front-left,front-right
                 Stereo
    resample method: copy
    module: 10
    client: 1884 <Chromium>
    properties:
        application.icon_name = "chromium-browser"
        media.name = "Playback"
        application.name = "Chromium"
        native-protocol.peer = "UNIX socket client"
        native-protocol.version = "33"
        application.process.id = "2993986"
        application.process.user = "aneutrino"
        application.process.host = "xiexie"
        application.process.binary = "Discord"
        application.language = "en_US.UTF-8"
        window.x11.display = ":0"
        application.process.machine_id = "13335995d81e4f4faf75ac28835b4f8c"
        module-stream-restore.id = "sink-input-by-application-name:Chromium"
```

in the example, above it was `Discord` chat application using `chrome-browser` making noises `PID 2993986` I have entered to settings and disabled sounds in it, but alternatively I could simply kill it `kill 2993986`

Answer (score 3):

Run '`lsof | grep dev/snd`' as root. You'll see what processes have files in /dev/snd open.

Comment: On my machine, `lsof` shows a screen or two of output, and then it just sits. It does nothing anymore. Any clues on what could be wrong?